# \begin{tcb@savebox} on input line 22 ended by \end{center}, works when adding extra line

Tags: tcolorbox

```
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newtcolorbox{qq}[2][]{,
    #1,
}
\newcommand{\qa}[2]{
    \noindent
    \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
    \textbf{Q:} 
    #1
    \textbf{A:}
    #2
    \end{minipage}
    \vspace{1em}
}

\begin{document}
\qa{\begin{qq}
    \begin{center}
    hi
    \end{center}
\end{qq}}{hello}
\end{document}
```

This produces the error. When adding a line break in between "\qa{begin{qq}" and "\begin{center}" (so between line 18 and 19) the error is gone. I am wondering what is happening here.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newtcolorbox{qq}[2][]{,
    #1,
}
\newcommand{\qa}[2]{
    \noindent
    \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
    \textbf{Q:} 
    #1
    \textbf{A:}
    #2
    \end{minipage}
    \vspace{1em}
}

\begin{document}
\qa{\begin{qq}

    \begin{center}
    hi
    \end{center}
\end{qq}}{hello}
\end{document}
```

Comment: your colorbox has two arguments and so grabs the \begin. You probably meant `\newtcolorbox{qq}[1][]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentionned in comment, when you define `\newtcolorbox{qq}[2][]`, `LaTeX` expects the `qq` environment to be followed by 2 arguments:

1. the first is optional (due to [])
2. the second is mandatory.

However, in your usage within `\qa`, you only provide what is interpreted as part of the first argument (due to the way arguments are captured), leading to a confusion about where the environment's content actually begins.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newtcolorbox{qq}[1][]{%
    #1,
}
\newcommand{\qa}[2]{%
    \noindent
    \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
    \textbf{Q:}%
    #1
    \textbf{A:}%
    #2
    \end{minipage}
    \vspace{1em}
}

\begin{document}
\qa{\begin{qq}
    \begin{center}
    hi
    \end{center}
\end{qq}}{hello}
\end{document}
```